# "Argument of \@caption has extra }" error using \makemathbox inside caption

Tags: captions, mathtools

I have a math expression which I seem to be unable to use inside a caption. Here's what I want to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{$\mathrel{\xleftarrow{\mathmakebox[0.55em]{}}\hspace*{-0.4em}\smallsquare}$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I move the math out of the caption, it compiles fine.

(The example is slightly less than minimal; I thought it would be useful to show what the expression does. I can reproduce the problem with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{$\mathmakebox[0.55em]{}$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't produce any output.)

Comment: This is usually evidence for a fragile command in a moving argument: use `\protect\mathmakebox` when in a caption. On the other hand, `\hspace{0.55em}` should be equivalent; or, more simply, `${\longrightarrow}\smallsquare$`

Comment: Yup, does the trick. Thanks for the super-speedy answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error message is evidence for a fragile command in a moving argument; in this case it's `\mathmakebox`; when in a caption, use `\protect` in front of it.

Better, define a new command for complicated constructions:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\leftarrowbox{%
  \mathrel{\xleftarrow{\mathmakebox[0.55em]{}}\hspace*{-0.4em}\smallsquare}%
}
```

and in your document type `\leftarrowbox`.

I hope you're not loading `MnSymbol` just to get `\smallsquare`. See [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) for a workaround. With the standard fonts you can get away with

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\leftarrowbox}{%
  \leftarrow\mathrel{\mkern-2.5mu\xsmallsquare}
}
\newcommand{\xsmallsquare}{{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\square$}}}}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I had used a macro originally, but inlined it to produce my MWE. (As a general question: is it reasonable to include small macros in MWE's, if they increase readability?)

I am pulling in other stuff from `MnSymbol`, but I appreciate the `\mkern` tip too. Cheers

Comment: In this case it was probably better to add the definition.